# vmware not getting ip on dell r620

Tags: vmware-esxi, nic, drac

Installed a new ESXi 5.1 on a new Dell R620

When connecting to the iDrac (Enterprise) from the dedicated iDrac connection I can see 1 NIC connected (beside the integrated jack)

[image]

[image]

The problem is that when launching the server, the ESXi is NOT getting an IP - it shows as loop back IP

[image]

- DHCP is enabled
- Tried to restart management network

What's next?

Comment: That isnt a loop back thats a Apipa address. Out of intrest have you tryied the first nic port? Looks like thats plugged into the 2nd.

Comment: I will marry you :-) just plugged to first NIC, and it works. And if I only knew why it's like this - beats me. Reall didn't think it matters *feel free to post as answer

Comment: posted for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware usually takes DHCP from the first nic. From the screenshot it looks like that the network cable is plugged into NIC2. Try NIC1 and it should work. From there you can set NIC bindings to be NIC2 etc etc.